# ienumerable except method returning no differences

Tags: c#

```
   var list1 = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
    var list2 = new int[] { };
    var x = list2.Except(list1).ToList();
```

This doesnt return all elements from list1, `var x` is actually an empty list. according to [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) it should return all the elements in list1. Why is it not, and what am I missing.

> A sequence that contains the set difference of the elements of two sequences.

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_(set_theory)

Comment: You can translate `Enumerable.Except` with `"list2 without list1"` if you're unsure how it works.

Comment: Maybe you are looking for [Distinct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348436%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works just fine: returns all items from `list2` which do not exist in `list1`. And because `list2` is already empty result list is empty as well.

Look at *`first`* parameter description on the msdn:

> An `IEnumerable<T>` whose elements that are not also in second will be returned.

Comment: since List2 has no elements shouldnt it return all elements in list1? per your qoute? missred your qoute

Comment: No, it returns all items from `first` except items which are in `second`.

Answer (score 2):

The wording might be confusing on MSDN, but refer to set theory to understand it.

> A sequence that contains the **set difference** of the elements of two sequences.

A set difference is also called a [complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complement_%28set_theory%29) and is "is the set of elements in B but not in A".

With that in mind, an empty array `.Except` anything is still an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want

```
var list1 = new[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };
var list2 = new int[] { };
var x = list2.Union(list1).ToList();
```

Since you mentioned that you are expecting

> should return all the elements in list1